# In Get-WinEvent, which kind of interval of EndTime?

Tags: powershell

I used `Get-WinEvent` in Powershell to get eventlog in a time interval. To avoid data loss or repeat, I need to know the interval type of `StartTime` and `EndTime`.

In the following example in MSDN:

```
PS C:\> # Use the Where-Object cmdlet

PS C:\>$yesterday = (Get-Date) - (New-TimeSpan -Day 1)
PS C:\>Get-WinEvent -LogName "Windows PowerShell" | Where-Object     {$_.TimeCreated -ge $yesterday}

# Uses FilterHashTable

PS C:\>$yesterday = (Get-Date) - (New-TimeSpan -Day 1)
PS C:\>Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{LogName='Windows PowerShell'; Level=3; StartTime=$yesterday}
```

It seems that `StartTime` means ">=".

But I did not find any info about `EndTime`. what's it represent?  "<" or "<="?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EndTime` means `<=`. Just ran a test on my PC. When I set `EndTime=(get-date -Date "03.08.2015 14:07:27")` I get events on that precise time. Also the timestamps in the event log don't contain milliseconds, therefore filtering is done by 1 second precision.